# C++ formatting to display numbers in a row instead of a column

Tags: c++, format

This is part of a larger code I am doing but I have a question about the formatting. For this part I am using the following for loop which displays the numbers that are less or equal to rNumber.

My only question is how can I make it display the numbers in a row instead of a column since when I run the program, if for example rNumber is 5, it will display:

1

2

3

4

5

What I want is for it to display it like this :  1 2 3 4 5

```
else if (mNumber < rNumber)
    {
        cout << "\nYour number is too low, try again!. Here is a hint, pick between these!:" << endl;

        for (int i = ++mNumber; i <= rNumber; i++)
        {

            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You remove the `endl` and you add `" "` instead?

Comment: remove the endl and add a space to your printing: `cout << i << " ";`

Comment: `endl` is basically "\n". Just replace it with a space.

Comment: instead of endl use '\t' ..tabbed result

Comment: please dont use stuff that you dont understand. Each time you use `std::endl` a kitten dies in china. Just joking, but seriously dont use stuff just because "it works"

Comment: Thank you so much that worked perfectly I am sorry for the dumb question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of endl and just add a string with a space in between

```
 cout << i << " ";
```

endl stands for end of line.

Comment: `std::endl` is not only adds a end of line, but also flushes, thats why in general `'\n'` is prefered